# WPF: How to remake Mahapps Metro application to class library?

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I have a WPF Mahapps Metro style application.
That is the MainWindow containing Usercontrol, and inside it works with other Usercontrols like Wizard Pages.

Now I am trying to remake it to a class library to use it in WiX Bootstraper application.

The one of problems is: where place resources which are in

```
 <Application.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
...
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

I have placed it to the main Usercontrol xml but it is an error:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary> <------------x:Key required?
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ViewModelAlreadyInstalledPage}">
            <view:AlreadyInstalledPage/>
        </DataTemplate>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the `DataTemplate` inside the `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ViewModelAlreadyInstalledPage}">
        <view:AlreadyInstalledPage />
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```